# Convert generic class into XML string of specific structure

Tags: c#, xml, generics

There is a need to have a specific structure of XML string when interacting with 3rd party system. Here are two examples:

```
<DocumentElement>
 <Country>
  <CountryCode>UA</CountryCode>
  <Name>Ukraine</Name>
 </Country>
</DocumentElement>
```

and

```
<DocumentElement>
 <Currency>
  <CurrencyCode>UAH</CurrencyCode>
  <Description>Hryvnia</Description>
 </Currency>
</DocumentElement>
```

Like you can see it is a common wrapping tag `DocumentElement`.
So, here is **approach #1**:

Have a wrapper class:

```cs
[XmlRoot("DocumentElement")]
public class DocumentElement<T>
{
    public T InnerObject { get; set; }

    public DocumentElement(){}
    public DocumentElement(T some)
    {
        InnerObject = some;
    }
}
```

And replace `InnerObject` after conversion:

```cs
public static string GetXml<T>(T instance) where T : class
{
    var wrapper = new DocumentElement<T>(instance);
    var writer = new StringWriter();
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DocumentElement<T>));
    serializer.Serialize(writer, wrapper);
    return writer.ToString().Replace("InnerObject", instance.GetType().Name);
}
```

Or, **approach #2**:

Throw away `DocumentElement` and just concat a needed string:

```
public static string GetXml<T>(T instance) where T : class
{
    var writer = new StringWriter();
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    serializer.Serialize(writer, instance);
    return "<DocumentElement>" + writer.ToString() + "</DocumentElement>";
}
```

Both approaches produce a needed format but neither looks clean enough.
Maybe, someone can suggest a better approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at  [How to: Specify an Alternate Element Name for an XML Stream](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/how-to-specify-an-alternate-element-name-for-an-xml-stream?view=netframework-4.8). 
Although it is more code, I would use the mentioned [`XmlAttributeOverrides`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides) like so

```
public static string GetXml<T>(T instance, string sourceName = "InnerObject") where T : class
{
    var wrapper = new DocumentElement<T>(instance);
    var writer = new StringWriter();
    var overrides = CreateOverrides(typeof(DocumentElement<T>), instance.GetType().Name, sourceName);

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DocumentElement<T>), overrides);
    serializer.Serialize(writer, wrapper);
    return writer.ToString();
}
private static XmlAttributeOverrides CreateOverrides(Type type, string destinationName, string sourceName)
{
    var elementAttribute = new XmlElementAttribute() { ElementName = destinationName };
    var attributes = new XmlAttributes();
    attributes.XmlElements.Add(elementAttribute);
    var overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
    overrides.Add(type, sourceName, attributes);
    return overrides;
}
```